# Некорректная работа Itemtouchhelper Android

Tags: android, recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

Требуется вручную менять порядок в отображаемом RecyclerView (drag and drop), а также удалять свайпом. Используются возможности Itemtouchhelper. Для примера использовал статью https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf Всё сделал, как там было указано, элементы перемещаются, но вот анимация страдает [image: см. картинку]. Может, кто-то сталкивался с такими проблемами?

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос

Comment: Код использовался из статьи, которая указана выше в теле вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос был решен. Оказывается, некорректно работал метод Collections.swap Пришлось его заменить на удаление у вставку элементов "вручную" в блоке synchronized. Такие вот баги Андроида.